# Probability measure product space

Tags: measure-theory, pr.probability

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ and $(Y,C,\nu)$ be probability spaces, and let $m$ be the product measure. Let $f:X \times Y \rightarrow [0,\infty )$ be a $B \otimes C $ measurable function, $1 < p < \infty$, and define $f_x(y):=f(x,y)$.

What is the most general condition on $f$ to make sure that: $||f||_{L_p(m)}=\int{||f_x||_{L_p(\nu)}}d\mu(x)$ ?

I know that if $\int{|f_x(y)|^p}d\nu(y)$ is constant there is equality. But is it the only case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

yes, it is the only case. Denote $g(x)=(\int{|f(x,y)|^pd\nu(y))}^{1/p}$, then your condition is $||g||_1=||g||_p$ which is known to imply that $g$ is a constant function, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality).

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if under the same conditions as in the original question, is it always true that $||f||_{L_p(m)} \gt ∫||f_x||_{L_p(ν)}dμ(x)$? I think it can be proven using Tonelli's theorem and concave Jensen's inequality, but I'm not sure they are applicable here.